# RequestError(400, u'action_request_validation_exception', u'Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I am following https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl to index the data inside my django-model. 
I have defined my documents.py file as :->

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import Document , fields 
from django_elasticsearch_dsl.registries import registry
from abc.models import *
from elasticsearch_dsl import connections, field, analyzer


connections.create_connection(hosts=['localhost'], timeout=20)


@registry.register_document
class ParkingDocument(Document):
   class Index:
    # Name of the Elasticsearch index
    name = 'parking'
    # See Elasticsearch Indices API reference for available settings
    settings = {'number_of_shards': 1,
                'number_of_replicas': 0}

   class Django:
    model = ParkingLocation

    fields = [
        'created',
        'updated',
    ]
```

When i run the command 
    `python manage.py search_index --rebuild`.
I get error as mentioned in title. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using the old version of elasticsearch where [types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/mapping.html#mapping-type) is mandatory, but in your query, you are not including it.

In the current version of ES, types are deprecated [see](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/removal-of-types.html). Please provide which version of elasticsearch and client you are using ?

and follow these link and below to see the compitable versions:

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or later may only contain a
>   single mapping type. Indices created in 5.x with multiple mapping
>   types will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x. Types
>   will be deprecated in APIs in Elasticsearch 7.0.0, and completely
>   removed in 8.0.0.

Comment: Yes , I rectified my query by installing elasticsearch 6. Thank You !!